# TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do something like this architecture

[image: error]

Both data are `eagerTensor` types. But it crashes on the red part. I cannot post the code since it is from my client, I'm sorry. How can I do that?
I can post a dummy code instead:

```
eager1 = tf.random.uniform((1, 60, 512))
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(eager1)
eager2 = tf.random.uniform((1, 60, 512))(dense)
```

Comment: It's completely impossible to say anything here without seeing some code. Literally the only thing is "you're doing it wrong", since if you didn't, it would work. :shrug:

Comment: @xdurch0 I know, I'm sorry, I cannot give much details. I've posted some dummy code hope it helps

Comment: Well what is the last line supposed to do? You are creating a tensor from random values and calling it on the dense layer outputs? Tensors are not callable.

Comment: @xdurch0 then how can I reach my desired architecture?